# how to Understand complicated array declaration pointers, and &

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here are two lines of code:

```
int (*parry)[10]   = &arr   // Line # 1
int *(&arrRef)[10] = ptrs   // Line # 2
```

**Line # 1**:

`parry` is a pointer that points to an `int` array of size 10.
So does it mean:

- `parray[1]` points to the address of `arr`,
- `parray[2]` points to address of `arr`
- ...
- `parray[10]` points to address or `arr`?

When would I use `Line # 1`?

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(
{
 int arr[10] = { 3, 54  };
 int (*parry)[10] = &arr;
 std::cout << (*parry)[0] << " " << (*parry)[1] << " "  << (*parry)[3] << "  " << parry[4] << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 3, 54, 0, hex address of arr at index 4.

It seems like what inside `parry[0]` is a pointer that points to `arr` associated with the index. So, `parry[0]` ---> `arr[0]`.

**Line # 2**:

`arrRef` is a reference to an `int` array of size ten pointers. `arrRef` is referred to by `ptrs`.
So does it mean:

- `arry[1]` is an `int` pointer? ...
- `arry[10]` is an `int` pointer?

What example can this been used in?

Comment: Side: Have you seen [www.cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) ?

Comment: C/C++ use 0-indexing so `parray[0]` is an alias of `arr`. `parray[1]` is probably out of bound. but `(*parray)[1]` is an alias to `arr[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've cleaned up your question, I can see it wasn't what I originally thought. You say:

> parray is a pointer that points to an int array of size 10

so clearly you figured out the clockwise/spiral/cdecl stuff already.

> So does it mean: ... parray[10] points to address of arr

Firstly, arrays in C++ are indexed starting from zero, so you can access `arr[0] .. arr[9]` if there are 10 elements; `arr[10]` would be the eleventh, so is out of bounds.

Now, let's take your sentence apart:

> *`parray` is a pointer*

right, it isn't an array, it's a pointer. Now, let's consider what it is a pointer to:

> *an int array of size 10*

ok, if it *points to* that, then `*parray` must be (a reference to) the original array.

So, `(*parray)[0]` is the first element of the array, etc.

Note that you can easily test your intuition about all this by just printing things out, and seeing what you get. You'll either see pointers, and be able to compare the addresses, or you'll see integer values, or you'll get (hopefully informative) compile errors. Try it out!

Oh, and:

> When would I use line 1?

Only if you need to re-seat it, in general. For example, if you want to choose one of two different arrays based on some logic, and then ... perform further logic on whichever was selected.

---

Next, you said

> arrRef is a reference to an int array of size ten pointers.

Correct!

> arrRef is refer to by ptrs

No, `arrRef` *refers to* an array, the array has size 10, and its 10 elements are pointers-to-int. **Note** this is not the same type as the first array!

Since references can be used with the same syntax as the thing they refer to, we can use `arrRef` as an array.

So, `arrRef[0]` is the first element of the array, and it is a pointer-to-int.

> What example can this been used in?

The only common reason for using reference-to-array is to avoid pointer decay, allowing templates to deduce the number of elements.

Comment: I don't understand what a template is so I can't come up with an example. but I came up with an example for line1. thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

When in doubt, see the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

```
int (*parry)[10] = &arr;
```

`parry` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s.

```
int *(&arrRef)[10] = ptrs;
```

`arrRef` is a reference to an array of 10 pointers to int.

Example:

```
int main()
{
   int arr[10];
   int* ptrs[10];

   int (*parry)[10] = &arr;
   int *(&arrRef)[10] = ptrs;
}
```

Comment: That webpage should be a part of any C or C++ textbook chapter on pointers :)

Comment: plus1: link to the rule

Comment: Parsing C declarations (or expressions -- they are identical!) has nothing to do with going clockwise or in any other preconceived pattern. It is instead completely governed by the operator precedence and evaluation direction. The fact that a declaration or expression can be resolved by that rule is completely coincidental. For example, `int *arr[2][3]` cannot be solved that way; the `[]`s have higher precedence than `*` and must both be evaluated first, before spiraling.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, good point. Perhaps the rule can be refined to deal with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: It's not restricted to arrays -- a pointer to a function which returns a function pointer would apply `()` twice. The rule is simply *inside out* in operator precedence and eval order, not spiral or zig zag or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this statement

```
//line1// int (*parry)[10] = $arr
                            ^^^  ^^
```

there is a typo

There must be

```
//line1// int (*parry)[10] = &arr;
                            ^^^  ^^
```

It is assumed that `arr` is an array of type `int[10]`. For example

```
int arr[10];
```

And this declaration

```
int (*parry)[10] = &arr;
```

declares a pointer to this entire array.

As for this declaration

```
//line2// int *(&arrRef)[10] = ptrs;
                                  ^^^
```

then it is assumed that `ptrs` is an array of type `int *[10]` That is elements of the array have type `int *`. They are pointers.

And this declaration

```
int * (&arrRef)[10] = ptrs;
```

declares a reference to this array. A reference is in fact is an alias of an array.

In C++ 2014 you could define a reference to an array simpler.

For example

```
decltype( auto )arrRef = ( ptrs );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int a[10];

    decltype( auto )ra = ( a );

    std::cout << sizeof( a ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof( ra ) << std::endl;

    ra[0] = 10;

    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << ra[0] << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
40
40
10
10
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing C declarations it is valuable to remember, in the words of Kernighan and Ritchie, that "the syntax is an attempt to make the declaration and the use agree" (K&R, TCPL, 5.12). In other words, you can treat a declaration as an expression and simply apply the operators in the proper order. That will show you what type the declared identifier must have.

For example, in `int (*parry)[10]` you first apply the `*` operator, because it is in parentheses. This indicates that `parray` is a pointer. Then you apply the `[]` operator, indicating that the result of the dereferencing was an array; the `10` indicates the number of elements. The obtained element is of type int. Summing up: `parray` was a pointer to an array of int.

Declarations of references in C++ can not be solved that way because there is actually no operator which would create a reference, or dereference one; both operations are implicit in C++. The `&` symbol is used to signify references in declarations only (perhaps somewhat confusingly, because in expressions it's used to take an address). But if you think of the `&` in declarations as a `*` substitute to signify a reference instead of a pointer you should still be able to parse any declaration.