# What do each of these arrays mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I received lecture slides for C++ that merely mention these without explaining what they mean and what are their differences:

```
int (*arr)[]={...};
int *(arr[])={...};
int (&arr)[]={...};
int &(arr[])={...}; // not allowed?
```

What do each of these mean? I tried running a program with some of these, but I'm getting errors because I don't know what to put in the initialization list.

Comment: Pointer to an array of int, array of int pointers, reference to an array of int and an array of int references.

Comment: Related question that was posted today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862840/how-to-understand-complicated-array-declaration-pointers-and.

Comment: Oh - homework dump, then.  Downvotes all round.

Comment: I have my final exam tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `int (*arr)[] = { ... };`

  This is not an array at all. This is a *pointer* to an array of unknown size. Note that this a scalar type. It is just a data pointer, no different in nature from any other data pointer. Which means that the only way to use `{ ... }` initializer with it is to specify a single value of proper type inside the `{ ... }`. E.g.

  ```
  int (*arr)[] = { nullptr };
  ```

  which is the same as

  ```
  int (*arr)[] = nullptr;
  ```
- `int *(arr[]) = { ... };`

  This is indeed an array. The same thing can be expressed as

  ```
  int *arr[] = { ... };
  ```

  This is an array of `int *` pointers. It size will depend on how many initializers are supplied in `{ ... }`. E.g.

  ```
  int *arr[] = { nullptr, &some_int, &some_other_int };
  ```

  declares `arr` as an array of 3 pointers of type `int *`.
- `int (&arr)[] = { ... };`

  This is not an array per se. This is a *reference* to an array of unknown size. Again, the only legal `{ ... }` initializer in this case would be just one lvalue of type `int []` inside the `{ ... }`. If the array was declared `const`, you'd be able to attach it to a temporary array of `int`s using this syntax, e.g.

  ```
  const int (&arr)[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  ```

  But without `const` it is not possible. (I have my doubts about the legality of this even with `const` though. GCC accepts it.)
- `int &(arr[]) = { ... };`

  This is an attempt to declare an array of references. Not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

```
int (*arr)[]={...};  // pointer to array of int
int *(arr[])={...};  // array of int pointers
int (&arr)[]={...};  // a reference to an array of int
int &(arr[])={...};  // an array of int references
```

The last one though is illegal: [Why arrays of references are illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-arrays-of-references-are-illegal)